# Why do I need to click twice to fire up this jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have this:

```
$(".slideDownArrow").click(function(){
    currentBlockIndex++; 
    $('.secondLevel li').eq(currentBlockIndex).trigger('click');
});
```

and when I click on the `slideDownArrow` it works for me and many other people, but not for everyone - my client has to click twice to trigger the `secondLevel li` click event. What could be the cause of it and how could I fix this?

The `secondLevel li` click function:

```
$('.secondLevel li, .exteriorBox li').bind('click', function(){

    var el = $(this),
    elIndex = el.index();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: hArray[elIndex]
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: @j08691 edited my post with the rest of the code for it.

Comment: try event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();

Comment: it could be the browser. internet explorer doesn't allow jquery .click() event for security reasons. the trigger might be being block for the same reason.

Comment: If it works "for some people", then the cause it doesn't work for others could be Internet Explorer...

Comment: @JeremyThille do you have an idea how I could make it work for IE?

Comment: We still need more information . . . like the section of HTML that the code is acting on and the initial value of `currentBlockIndex` . . .

Comment: @Xeen I'm not even sure it's IE. And if it's IE, what version. I don't know what the console outputs. So no sorry, I don't have a ready-made answer :)

Comment: @James Waring : This example *is* in response to a user click, so that security issue should not apply. The problem is the implementation of the `click` event with trigger. Just use the native `click()` method of the DOM element (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Go straight to the [HtmlElement click method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) instead:

```
$('.secondLevel li')[currentBlockIndex].click();
```

Rather than use `get()`, `[]` returns the HTML element. `click` is the native click event generator.

*As the event is in response to a user click, you can ignore any comments about security reason. I have tried this on all browsers and no problems.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if this helps, I'll accept it tomorrow :) so far, for me it continues to work, will see about the client

Comment: Shame. Worked for most situations I had hit. Which specific browser/version is it not working on?